# Why isn't the innerHTML changing? Its supposed to count up when clicked

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't this work? I'm sure I have the class name correct.

```
document.querySelector(".up").addEventListener("click", function () {
    let status = document.querySelector(".counter").innerHTML;
    status++;
});
```

Comment: You make a variable and then you increment that variable. You never actually assign the result to the innerHTML afterwards.

Comment: you need to assign a value to innerHTML

Comment: Also, innerHTML returns a string and it would be best to parse it to a number before doing anything with it: `let status = parseInt(document.querySelector(".counter").innerHTML);`

Comment: There's a bit to unpack here, and other commenters have addressed your initial question. Some other things to think about: why `.innerHTML`? What if there's markup in that element? You wouldn't be able to use the increment operator on something like `<p>hi</p>`. Why not try to `parseInt()` from the `.innerText` instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector(".up").addEventListener("click", function () {
    let value = document.querySelector(".counter").innerHTML
    document.querySelector(".counter").innerHTML = value++
});
```

That's what you should do instead, but you must be sure you innerHTML is a number.

**Edit:**

So something like `parseInt()` should be used to parse the value of the `innerHTML` since it returns a string.

**E.g**

```
document.querySelector(".up").addEventListener("click", function () {
    let value = parseInt(document.querySelector(".counter").innerHTML)
    document.querySelector(".counter").innerHTML = value++
});
```

**But make sure the value of the innerHTML is a number**

Comment: Thank you! I understand that! that looks like something I couldve done. The other comments I'm trying to understand.

Comment: This produces "Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation" because you can only do `++` on variables, not on expressions.